# Fresh install of 14.04 - Gave up waiting for root device

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, uefi

I hope you can help me.
I've read many, many questions and solutions to my problem on here, however so far I have been unsuccessful in resolving the issue.

The system is a Asrock e350m1, 4GB RAM, Various random hard disks. (I've testing many installs on my disks!)

I have a fresh install of 14.04.1 LTS, but it will not start up.
Here is the message on boot.

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/0d594499-7bc3-4da6-a8e9-2127932c03fc does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!
```

Here's what I have tried so far:

I've checked that the uuid matches my disk with

```
sudo blkid
```

I've also checked that the entries in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` match the uuid.

In addition I've checked that the uuids in /etc/fstab are correct.

I've tried the boot repair tool: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Here's the pastebin result: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9553069/

I've done this, as instructed in other people's answers:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
reboot
```

I've set my `SATA COMBINED MODE` to disabled in my UEFI settings.

I've tried Ubuntu 12.04 too, but it has the same error.
Interestingly, Ubuntu 10.04, Fedora Core 21, Windows 8.1 all work right away.

Really at this stage, I am at a loss. I do not know what else to try :(

Please help me!
Thanks! :)